# uppercase first letter in play framework

Tags: jpa, groovy, playframework

I have installed jpagen module in my system in play framework. Which successfully generates class files but i want to generate setter and getter functions too using for get function i'm using the below code

```
#{list items:table.columns, as:'item' }
    public ${item.columnType} get${item.columnPropertyName} {
return ${item.columnPropertyName};
}

#{/list}
```

But it generates with first letter with small case 
eg: getid()

But it shoud be getId()

how can i achieve this.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's true groovy, then

```
public ${item.columnType} get${item.columnPropertyName.capitalize()} {
```

should work (it uses the [capitalize method attached to String](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#capitalize%28%29))